# BigQuery Bug: SELECT of aliased field fails if scoped aggregation in subquery

Tags: google-bigquery

This query fails:

```
SELECT
  g.repository.url,
  cnt,
FROM
  (SELECT
    repository.url,
    COUNT(payload.pages.action) WITHIN RECORD as cnt,
  FROM publicdata:samples.github_nested) g
LIMIT 10
```

With the error:

```
Field 'g.repository.url' not found; did you mean 'repository.url'?
```

It looks like aliased fields in the SELECT clause don't work when the SELECT includes a field calculated from a scoped aggregation in the subquery and you don't have any JOINs.

I found a related [bug](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=40) which is labelled as fixed but I think the presence of a scoped aggregation in the subquery might be an edge case that wasn't covered.

This query does work:

```
SELECT
  g.repository.url,
  cnt,
FROM
  (SELECT
    repository.url,
    99 as cnt,
  FROM publicdata:samples.github_nested) g
LIMIT 10
```

Should the first query work? (I can obviously work around this by removing the aliases from the SELECT clause but the SQL is actually generated by a querying tool we're using so it's not easy for us to fix).

Comment: I think if it IS a bug, you're on the wrong site to mention it. Did you try opening a new issue on the "code.google.com" site? seems like a bug report would go there before going on Stack :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is a bug, first query should work.

Comment: Thanks. Opened bug: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=219

Comment: It looks like this bug has been fixed. The first query now works.

Answer (score 0):

What if you replaced the first query with this:

```
SELECT
  g.url,
  g.cnt
FROM
  (SELECT
    repository.url,
    COUNT(payload.pages.action) WITHIN RECORD as cnt,
  FROM publicdata:samples.github_nested) g
LIMIT 10
```